gRPC: What is the time permitted by the underlying HTTP/RPC protocol? How to access it in C#?
I am implementing a C# service that implements the WaitOperationRequest of the Package google.longrunning. For the Duration of the WaitOperation the documentation says:
The maximum duration to wait before timing out. If left blank, the wait will be at most the time permitted by the underlying HTTP/RPC protocol. If RPC context deadline is also specified, the shorter one will be used.
What is the "time permitted by the underlying HTTP/RPC protocol" and how do I access it in the C# implementation of gRPC?

I have the timeout given by the client, and I have the deadline of the gRPC call. But the documentation specifically says: "If RPC context deadline is also specified, the shorter one will be used.", so this specifies that not the deadline of the gRPC call is meant.
However, the gRPC documentation about deadlines says:
"By default, gRPC does not set a deadline which means it is possible for a client to end up waiting for a response effectively forever."
Doesn't this imply that if the deadline and gRPC channel is configured correctly, the call can last forever and the HTTP/RPC protocol should not be another underlying mechanism that might cancel the call?
